# GET Service call is not getting called from Controller

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

i am trying to introduce Angular into one of my old application. But not sure why this is not calling the Service. Below is the Code in the JS File. Earlier i got error in browser saying $http cannot be resolved . So i just passed it in the function.

```
var app = angular.module('ldlApp', []);
app.controller('ldlController', function($scope,$http) {
  console.log(" Inside Controller **** ");
  $scope.message = 'Hello from LDL Controller !!!! ';
  $scope.BLT_LDL_DECESION_LOAN_DATA = [];
  console.log(" Going to Hit the Service ***** ");
  $http.get("/Services/ldl/getdetails")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.BLT_LDL_DECESION_LOAN_DATA = response.data;
      console.log("BLT_LDL_DECESION_LOAN_DATA: 
            "+JSON.stringify($scope.BLT_LDL_DECESION_LOAN_DATA));
      });
  });
```

Below is the REST Controller in java File

```
@RestController
public class LoanDecesionController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/Services/ldl/getdetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
   @ResponseBody
   @Transactional
   public List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> getdetails() throws Exception {
      System.out.println(" Inside Service **** ");
      List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> dataMap = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>();
      LinkedHashMap<String, Object> responsedataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      responsedataMap.put("SUCESS", "Called the service ");
      dataMap.add(responsedataMap);
      return dataMap; 
   }

}
```

In Browser i could see message like

```
Inside Controller **** 
Going to Hit the Service *****
```

Below is something i am seeing in network tab .

```
Request URL: https://*****-*****-*****.com/Services/ldl/getdetails
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 10.***.***.49:553
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

But i am not getting the sysouts in controller. So whether the problem is really with response or is it hitting the service.

Comment: Please indent your code, it's unreadable.

Comment: And use debugging tools (specifically your browser's Network tab) to see whether the request is being transmitted properly.

Comment: As @chrylis said, check the network tab. I can guess that your request didn't return HTTP 200, so `then` is not fired. `then` is only fired on a successful response from the server, try adding a `catch` to print if the server returned an error HTTP return code.

Comment: Updated the question with what i am seeing in the browser network tab

Comment: you get a 302 which is a redirect. In the answer there must be a _Location_ header giving the url to which the redirect points. You have to extract that and post a new request to this url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my existing application is blocking the URL and not allowing to hit any other URLs . Thanks everyone for the help and giving insight to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when using `@Transactional` and `@ResquestMaping` spring boot don't auto-configure URL mappings. remove `@Transactional` from your method and try to manage transactions somewhere else in your code